# How to es6 module import babylonjs in webpack for open source RTS game

Tags: typescript, webpack, babylonjs

I am working on a game that works fine when I include babylonjs in the head:

however when importing it in webpack,

import BABYLON from 'babylonjs'

for some reason my game its giving

(10,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'babylonjs'.

https://github.com/QuantumInformation/Density-Wars/blob/master/lib/game.ts#L10

BABYLON is still undefined

https://github.com/QuantumInformation/Density-Wars/blob/master/lib/game.ts#L29

If I use `var BABYLON =  require('babylonjs')`
then BABYLON is undefined

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add its declarations file? Something like [this](https://github.com/BabylonJS/Samples/blob/master/Scenes/BoxMonger/babylon.d.ts) (but needs a tiny modification.)

Answer (score 4):

Your [declarations file](https://github.com/QuantumInformation/Density-Wars/blob/master/babylonjs.d.ts) doesn't define the `"babylonjs"` module. Just add those lines at the end:

```
declare module "babylonjs" {
  export = BABYLON;
}
```

Or maybe `export default BABYLON`. Depends on the module itself.

Answer (score 0):

If babylon is not defined, then the only reason is that you did not load it.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your game.ts, or whatever *.ts file you have, you need to include BABYLON

```
import BABYLON = require('babylonjs')
```